# Convert a number m to n using minimum number of given operations

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

**Question:**

Given 2 integers N and M. Convert a number N to M using minimum number of given operations.

The operations are:

- Square N (N = N^2)
- Divide N by a prime integer P if N is divisible by P (N = N / P and N % P == 0)

**Contrants:**

```
N, M <= 10^9
```

Example:

```
N = 12, M = 18
```

The minimum operations are:

- N /= 2 -> N = 6
- N = N^2 -> N = 36
- N /= 2 -> N = 18

**My take:**

I'm trying to use BFS to solve this problem. For each number, the available edges to other numberers are the operations. But it got Time Limit Exceeded. Is there any better way to solve this?

Here is my BFS code:

```
queue<pair<int,int> > q;
vector<long long> pr;
ll m,n;
bool prime[MAXN+1];

void solve()
{
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        pii x=q.front();
        q.pop();
        if (x.first==m)
        {
            cout << x.second;
            return;
        }
        if (x.first==1) continue;
        for(ll k:pr)
        {
            if (k>x.first) break;
            if (x.first%k==0) q.push({x.first/k,x.second+1});
        }
        q.push({x.first*x.first,x.second+1});
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to point something: if M have a prime factor that don't have N so the conversion is impossible, because the square operation only add more of the existing prime factors of N and the division operation remove prime factors from N.

Comment: What coding language is this?  What is pii and ll?

Comment: You declare prime, but do not use it anywhere.  What is that about?

Comment: @HerlySQR Hmmm. Given `N,M` looks like the greatest-common-factor/least common-multiple may lead directly to the _minimum number_.

Comment: bool prime[x] = true if x is a prime number, the part to initialize `prime[]` is removed to make the code more simple

Comment: Discovering all the primes < 10^9 will take a long time, and if you use it nowhere, is a total waste of time

Comment: I don't think this is the best way to do what you want, you could try this (I'm also not sure):
1) Somehow get the canonical decomposition of the numbers N and M.
2) Check if the conversion is possible (for what I said before).
3) In every prime factor compare the exponents, if the N is bigger than from M then use the division operation for that factor until is equal (prioritize this).
4) If the N is smalller than from M then repeat the square operation until is bigger and then use the divide operation until is equal.

Obviously this should consider a lot of things, but the idea is that.

Comment: If there is a solution by math, you might not need to search for it

Comment: @HerlySQR i tried your approach but only got around half of the test cases. There might be something else that needs to be considered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm uses the decomposition on `N` and `M` in prime factors, keeping trace of the corresponding exponents.

If `M` has a prime factor that `N` does not have, there is no solution (the code returns -1).

If `N`  has some prime factors that `M` doesn't have, then the first step is to divide `N` by these primes.
The corresponding number of operations is the sum of the corresponding exponents.

At this stage, we get two arrays `A` and `B` corresponding to the exponents of the common prime factors, for `N` and `M`.
It is worth noting that at this stage, the values of the primes involved is not relevant anymore, only the exponents matter.

Then one must determine the minimum number of squares (= multiplications by 2 of the exponents).
The is the smallest `k` such that `A[i] >= 2^k B[i]` for all indices `i`.
The number of multiplications is added to the number of operations only once, as all exponents are multiplied by 2 at the same time.

Last step is to determine, for each pair `(a, b) = (A[i], B[i])`, the number of subtractions needed to go from `a` to `b`, while implementing exactly `k` multiplications by 2. This is performed with the following rules:

```
- if (k == 0) f(a, b, k) = a-b
- Else:
    - if ((a-1)*2^k >= b: f(a, b, k) = 1 + f(a-1, b, k)
    - else: f(a, b, k) = f(2*a, b, k-1)
```

The complexity is dominated by the decomposition in primes factors: O(sqrt(n))

**Code:**

This code is rather long, but a great part consists if helper routines needed for debugging and analysis.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

void print (const std::vector<int> &v, const std::string s = "") {
    std::cout << s;
    for (auto &x: v) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void print_decomp (int n, const std::vector<int> &primes, const std::vector<int> &mult) {
    std::cout << n << " = ";
    int k = primes.size();    
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        std::cout << primes[i];
        if (mult[i] > 1) std::cout << "^" << mult[i];
        std::cout << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void prime_decomp (int nn, std::vector<int> &primes, std::vector<int> &mult) {
    int n = nn;
    if (n <= 1) return;

    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        primes.push_back(2);
        int cpt = 1;
        n/= 2;
        while (n%2 == 0) {n /= 2; cpt++;}
        mult.push_back (cpt);
    }
    int max_prime = sqrt(n);
    int p = 3;
    while (p <= max_prime) {
        if (n % p == 0) {
            primes.push_back(p);
            int cpt = 1;
            n/= p;
            while (n%p == 0) {n /= p; cpt++;}
            mult.push_back (cpt);
            max_prime = sqrt(n);
        }
        p += 2;
    }
    if (n != 1) {
        primes.push_back(n);
        mult.push_back (1);
    }
    print_decomp (nn, primes, mult);
}

//  Determine the number of subtractions to go from a to b, with exactly k multiplications by 2

int n_sub (int a, int b, int k, int power2) {
    if (k == 0){
        if (b > a) exit(1);
        return a - b;
    }
    //if (a == 1) return n_sub (2*a, b, k-1, power2/2);
    if ((a-1)*power2 >= b) {
        return 1 + n_sub(a-1, b, k, power2);
    } else {
        return n_sub (2*a, b, k-1, power2/2);
    }
    return 0;
}

//  A return of -1 means no possibility

int n_operations (int N, int M) {
    int count = 0;
    if (N == M) return 0;
    if (N == 1) return -1;
    std::vector<int> primes_N, primes_M, expon_N, expon_M;
//  Prime decomposition
    prime_decomp(N, primes_N, expon_N);
    prime_decomp (M, primes_M, expon_M);
//  Compare decomposition, check if a solution can exist, set up two exponent arrays
    std::vector<int> A, B;
    int index_A = 0, index_B = 0;
    int nA = primes_N.size();
    int nB = primes_M.size();
    while (true) {
        if ((index_A == nA) && (index_B == nB)) {
            break;
        }
        if ((index_A < nA) && (index_B < nB)) {
            if (primes_N[index_A] == primes_M[index_B]) {
                A.push_back(expon_N[index_A]);
                B.push_back(expon_M[index_B]);
                index_A++; index_B++;
                continue;
            }
            if (primes_N[index_A] < primes_M[index_B]) {
                count += expon_N[index_A];
                index_A++;
                continue;
            }
            return -1;  // M has a prime that N doesn't have: impossibility to go to M
        }
        if (index_B != nB) {        // impossibility
            return -1;
        }
        for (int i = index_A; i < nA; ++i) {
            count += expon_N[i];    // suppression of primes in N not in M
        }
        break;
    }
    std::cout << "1st step, count = " << count << "\n";
    print (A, "exponents of N: ");
    print (B, "exponents of M: ");
    
//  Determination of the number of multiplications by two of the exponents (= number of squares)
    int n = A.size();
    int n_mult2 = 0;
    int power2 = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        while (power2*A[i] < B[i]) {
            power2 *= 2;
            n_mult2++;
        }
    }
    count += n_mult2;
    std::cout << "number of squares = " << n_mult2 << "  -> " << power2 << "\n";
    
//  For each pair of exponent, determine the number of subtractions, 
//  with a fixed number of multiplication by 2

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        count += n_sub (A[i], B[i], n_mult2, power2);
    }
    
    return count;
}


int main() {
    int N, M;
    std::cin >> N >> M;
    auto ans = n_operations (N, M);
    std::cout << ans << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```